# Accessing CFArray causes crash in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-foundation

My following code crashes with EXC_BAD_ACCESS, and I do not understand why.  My initial understanding is that the memory retention in this case should be automatic, but it seems I am wrong... Maybe someone can help. Thank you!                              The code is written in Swift 5 and runs on iOS 15.2 in XCode 13.2.1.

Casting to NSArray causes trouble...

```
let someFont = CGFont("Symbol" as CFString)!
if let cfTags: CFArray = someFont.tableTags {
   let nsTags = cfTags as NSArray
   print(nsTags.count) // Prints: 16
   let tag0 = nsTags[0] // CRASH: Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=257, ...)
 }
```

Alternatively, using CFArray-API causes also trouble (The crash message is about a misaligned pointer but the root cause seems also the bad access, which occurs e.g. if I replace UInt32.self by UInt8.self, and hence eliminate the alignment problem).

```
let someFont = CGFont("Symbol" as CFString)!
if let cfTags: CFArray = someFont.tableTags {
     print(CFArrayGetCount(cfTags)) // Prints: 16
     let tag0Ptr: UnsafeRawPointer = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(cfTags, 0)!
     tag0Ptr.load(as: UInt32.self)// CRASH :Thread 1: Fatal error: load from misaligned raw pointer
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here is that the `CGFont` API uses some advanced C-isms in their storage of table tags, which really doesn't translate to Swift: [`CGFontCopyTableTags()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/1396392-cgfontcopytabletags?language=objc) returns a `CFArrayRef` which doesn't actually contain objects, but integers. (This is technically allowed through `CFArray`'s interface: it accepts `void *`s in C, into which you can technically stuff any integer which fits in a pointer, even if the pointer value is nonsense...) Swift expects `CFArray`s and `NSArray`s to only ever contain valid objects and pointers, and it treats the return values as such — this is why accessing via `NSArray` also fails (Swift expects an object but the value isn't an object, so it can't be accessed like a pointer, or retained, or any of the things that the runtime might expect to do).

Your second code snippet is closer to how you'll need to access the value: `CFArrayGetValueAtIndex` appears to return a pointer, but the value you're getting back isn't a real pointer — it's actually an integer stored in the array directly, masquerading as a pointer.

The equivalent to the Obj-C example from the `CGFontCopyTableTags` docs of

```
tag = (uint32_t)(uintptr_t)CFArrayGetValue(table, k);
```

would be

```
let tag = unsafeBitCast(CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(cfTags, 0), to: UInt.self)
```

(Note that you need to cast to `UInt` and not `UInt32` because `unsafeBitCast` requires that the input value and the output type have the same alignment.)

In my simulator, I'm seeing a tag with a value of `1196643650` (`0x47535542`), which definitely isn't a valid pointer (but I don't otherwise have domain knowledge to validate whether this is the tag you're expecting).

Comment: Hi Itai, thank you very much for your swift  and very helpful reply!  The unsafeBitCast does the trick and I get the tag out! Great! These "advanced C-isms" is something to look out for, but good to know about these and how to deal with them in Swift in the future!

Comment: @Céline FWIW, code like this should be _very_ rare. This would trip up API consumers in pure C too unless they knew about this approach ahead of time, and it's not something that you should be too worried about. For the future: ideally, docs will hopefully keep you abreast of surprises like this... so pray that it's documented!

Comment: Hi Itai, thank you for the insights! Good stuff!!